# Datatable select row issue

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable with values. I need to get the row data which is selected. So I'm trying to get a row like demo code. But I'm getting an error `"TypeError: oTable.$ is not a function"`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var oTable;
oTable = $("#products").dataTable({...});

oTable.$('tr').click( function () {
var data = oTable.fnGetData( this );});
```

But the same code without `.$('tr')` function is working good like below code. So what is the problem in `oTable.$('tr').click()`...this is way example given.

```
oTable.click(function() { }); // working fine
```

Comment: What's the value of `oTable`?

Comment: oTable value is Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some code that I use to select a single row from a large table:

```
$("#patienttable tr").click(function() {
       var passthis = $(this).find("#localid").html();
       $.post("php/setsessionvariable.php",
                                       {sessionval: passthis}      );
       window.location.href = 'http://xxx.xxxxxxx/xxx/xxx.php';
```

When the row is clicked it grabs a single ID from the row, and passes it to a php script
that makes that ID the session variable.

So I wonder if yours might work better if you put the name of the table in the parentheses.

Let's see what others might say.

Answer (score 1):

`oTable` is a DataTables object, not a jQuery object. So you can't use `oTable.$('tr')` (which is wrong regardless).

I'm not sure how you are pin-pointing the `tr` you are looking for, but if you want to trigger a click event, you will need to get the jQuery object

```
var row = $("table#products tr[id=123]");
row.click();
```

Comment: Wrong http://www.datatables.net/api from the first example: `oTable.$('tr:odd').css('backgroundColor', 'blue');`

Comment: Hmm, got plenty of DataTables experience, but this is new to me :-)